# Change visibility of one button by clicking another button

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to change visibility of two buttons when pressing one of them.

So say I have an "on" and an "off" button. When I press the on button, I want the on button to hide itself and the off button to show, and vice versa.

How could one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to inform on to point.

1. How can I handle the visibility ?
2. How can I listen to a click event ?

**How can I handle the visibility** ?

You can handle the visibility of a view by using the [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:visibility) property.

This property controls the visibility of the view.

Must be one of the following constant values.

- **GONE**  Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.
- **INVISIBLE**  Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it).
- **VISIBLE**   Visible on screen (the default value)

Now you know how you could display or not and element on your view.

**How can I listen to a click event ?**

Simply add on onClickListner on your button

*Sample Code*

```
btnOff, btnOn // your buttons

btnOff.setOnclickListner {
  // handle visibility 
  btnOn.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

BTW. If you want an On/Off button, you should use [Toggle Buttons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton) there are like the switch buttons you used to have on settings screens

[image]

Comment: Say I would want a button with an icon I made in illustrator rather than text, should I make a button and put an image view over it, or is there a better way? I assume there must be a better way, to avoid scaling issues.

Comment: You can add your image/icon directly on the button using ```android:drawableStart``` (if you want the image on the left side, use End for the right side), but this is another question as your original... If my answer is correct, please mark it as the accepted answer in order to mark this question as finish. thank.

Try your button icon by your own way, if you don't succeed, create a new question and I may help you to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

See this example in Kotlin, adapt it for your own needs:

```
    val onButton = Button(this)
    val offButton = Button(this)
    onButton.setOnClickListener {
        onButton.visibility = INVISIBLE
        offButton.visibility = VISIBLE
    }
    offButton.setOnClickListener {
        onButton.visibility = VISIBLE
        offButton.visibility = INVISIBLE
    }
```

Or in Java:

```
    Button onButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onButton);
    Button offButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.offButton);

    onButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButton.visibility = INVISIBLE;
            offButton.visibility = VISIBLE;
        }
    });

    offButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onButton.visibility = VISIBLE;
            offButton.visibility = INVISIBLE;
        }
    });
```